# Get sectionIndex titles based on contact name

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

In my app I have a db with 50k+ contacts. To display them on list view, I need to calculate the index section titles to display them on the right side.

However my logic is taking time around 3-6 seconds to prepare the datasource.

```
-(NSArray *)getSectionTitleBasedOn:(NSString*)sortBy{

    for (RealmContact *contact in contactSource){

        if (contact.firstName.length>0) {
            if ([sortBy isEqualToString:@"FirstName"]) {

                NSString *firName= [contact.firstName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
                NSString *regex = @"^[A-Za-z]+";
                NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
                BOOL result = [test evaluateWithObject:firName];

                if (contact.firstName.length>0 && result)
                {
                    [nameDic setObject:@"firstletter" forKey:[[contact.firstName substringToIndex:1]uppercaseString]];
                }else{
                     [nameDic setObject:@"firstletter" forKey:@"#"];
                }
            }
            if ([sortBy isEqualToString:@"LastName"]) {
                //same
            }
            if ([sortBy isEqualToString:@"Company"]) {
                //same
            }

        }
    }
    NSLog(@"dic %@",nameDic);
    return [[nameDic allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}
```

I'm wondering if there is anything I could do to improve this.

```
 NSString *firName= [contact.firstName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
 NSString *regex = @"^[A-Za-z]+";
  NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
  BOOL result = [test evaluateWithObject:firName];
```

I'm doing this to check if string contain special chars or invalid chars.

After I get the array, I sort it and return the array. The output would be:

```
dic {
    "#" = firstletter;
    A = firstletter;
    B = firstletter;
    C = firstletter;
    D = firstletter;
    E = firstletter;
    F = firstletter;
    G = firstletter;
    H = firstletter;
    I = firstletter;
    J = firstletter;
    K = firstletter;
    L = firstletter;
    M = firstletter;
    N = firstletter;
    O = firstletter;
    P = firstletter;
    Q = firstletter;
    R = firstletter;
    S = firstletter;
    T = firstletter;
    U = firstletter;
    V = firstletter;
    W = firstletter;
    X = firstletter;
    Y = firstletter;
    Z = firstletter;
}
```

Comment: I did this: https://pastebin.com/ixHsPSxh Tested on OSX Simulator, seems faster (x10, but didn't do more tests). Also, small error on your code: `if (contact.firstName.length>0 && result)` and `[nameDic setObject:@"firstletter" forKey:[[contact.firstName substringToIndex:1]uppercaseString]];` should use `firName` instead of `contact.firstName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this:

```
NSArray *sortedLetters = nil;
NSMutableSet *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"AZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN"];
for (RealmContact *contact in _dataSource)
{
    NSString *firName = [[contact firstName] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    if ([firName length])
    {
        unichar c = [[firName uppercaseString] characterAtIndex:0];
        if ([charSet characterIsMember:c])
        {
            [set addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", c]];
        }
        else
        {
            [set addObject:@"#"];
        }
    }
}
sortedLetters = [[set allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

What are the differences?
• I used of a `NSSet` instead of a `NSDictionary` for the unicity of first letters. I find useless to use a `NSDictionary` with a unused value and just for the unicity of the keys.
• I used `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` instead of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`. In theory, the code of `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` should stop at the first char which isn't of the set, and not continue until the end of the string like `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`.
• I guess that `characterIsMember:` is faster than a Regex/Predicate.
• Since you are only interested in uppercase, I translated it before doing the test, and not after, that could also speed the predicate in your case.

Also, small errors on your code:

```
if (contact.firstName.length>0 && result)
```

and

```
[nameDic setObject:@"firstletter" forKey:[[contact.firstName substringToIndex:1]uppercaseString]];
```

should use `firName` instead of `contact.firstName`.

On [this test sample](https://pastebin.com/ixHsPSxh), my solution seems to be faster than yours (x10).
I tested quickly on a OS X App (not iOS). I didn't do a lot of testings, but it may worth a try.

I don't know if it just for the question, but, the code optimization you could do:

```
NSString *stringToTest = nil;
if ([sortBy isEqualToString:@"FirstName"]) 
{
    stringToTest = contact.firstName;
}
else if ([sortBy isEqualToString:@"LastName"]) 
{
    stringToTest = contact.lastName;
}
else if ([sortBy isEqualToString:@"Company"]) 
{
    stringToTest = contact.companyName;
}
stringToTest = [stringToTest stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];    
if ([stringToTest length])
{
    //Do the code with stringToTest
}
```

It's for less code duplication and also use of if/else

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Comment: For curiosity, before you said your solution was taking "3-6 seconds". And now? Did you get enough improvement?

Comment: it  is instant now. It is taking 2-3 seconds for 200k + contacts.

Comment: Great! One small optimization to add maybe would be if you have that much contact, you may consider that there will have all letters and others, then you may want to do `if ([set count] == 27){break;}` It may or not fasten a little.