# Extracting the first character of names in a string array into another array

Tags: arrays, swift

I am working with a string array that has about 1100 employee names.

I want to extract the first characters of the employee names so that i can divide the names in table view alphabetically and in different sections. Just like how the contacts app on iPhone does.

i tried this for extraction

```
var first_char = [String]()
while (i < employeenames.count)//employeenames is the names array 
    {
 first_char.append(String(employeenames[i].prefix(1)))
 i+=1
}
```

This way I am getting the desired characters but the code is taking really long. Also I want to count how many times "A" or "B" shows up in first_char array. Which is again taking another many seconds and smoking the CPU.

Please someone help me with this.

Comment: I made something similar in Objective-C https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675849/get-sectionindex-titles-based-on-contact-name/45772425#45772425 You can get some ideas...

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220002/how-to-group-by-the-elements-of-an-array-in-swift.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to do a "group by" operation on the array of names.

You want to group by the first character, so:

```
let groups = Dictionary(grouping: employeenames, by: { String($0.first!).uppercased() })
```

The return value will be `[Character: [String]]`.

To count how many times `A` shows up, just do:

```
groups["A"].count
```

Comment: `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` is part of the Swift  4 standard library ...

Comment: @MartinR Oh yes it is! I didn't know that until now! Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
let employeenames = ["Peter", "John", "Frank"]
let firstChars = employeenames.map { String($0.first ?? Character("")) }
```

The order of the resulting single-character array will be the same as the order of the `employeenames` array. If you need sorting:

```
let sortedFirstChars = firstChars.sorted()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
let employee: [String] = ["James", "Tom", "Ben", "Jim"]
```

You can simply write

```
let firstCharacters = employee.compactMap { $0.first }
```

Result

```
print(firstCharacters)
["J", "T", "B", "J"]
```

### Sorting

If you want the initial characters sorted you can add this line

```
let sortedFirstCharacters = firstCharacters.sorted()

["B", "J", "J", "T"]
```

### Occurrencies

```
let occurrencies = NSCountedSet(array: firstCharacters)

let occurrenciesOfJ = occurrencies.count(for: Character("J"))
// 2
```